# Is there a way to convert elasticsearch's eql to dsl?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, eql

I want to convert elasticsearch's eql to dsl?

I only found a way to convert sql to dsl.

I'm trying to parse elastic detection rules.

The rule shows the query as eql.

I'd like to change it to a dsl.

please help me.

I couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere.